# How to instrument Angular CLI to report coverage on all source files

Tags: code-coverage, angular-cli, karma-coverage

When running `ng test --code-coverage` only coverage for source files that are undergoing tests are reported in the coverage report. How to configure instrumentation to include all source files (e.g. all `.ts` files in `src/app` folder)?

I have tried different things:

- Following https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1735 I tried replacing the suggested context definition. This does not work at all in my case. Loads of errors are outputted and no tests are executed
- Remove istanbul as dependency and rely solely on `karma-coverage`, where it is possible to configure `includeAllSources: true` - however Angular CLI cannot run without `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter`
- A combination of the above with `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` as a dependency - no difference from the original setup

There has to be some way to instrument Angular CLI to include all source files. Adding empty specs seems tedious and error-prone, since coverage will not show up at all if the class/source file is not undergoing test and you therefore manually have to check whether it's included in the coverage report or not.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Various information:

ng --version

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.8
node: 6.11.3
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.8
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-jquery": "2.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-json-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('karma-spec-reporter'),
            require('karma-htmlfile-reporter'),
            require('karma-json-reporter'),
            //require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        files: [
        ],
        client:{
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        // coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        //     reports: [ 'html', 'text', 'text-summary', 'json' ],
        //     fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        // },

        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: ['spec', 'kjhtml', 'html', 'json', 'coverage'],
        preprocessors: {
            'src/app/*.ts': ['coverage']
        },
        htmlReporter: {
            outputFile: 'testresults/index.html',
            pageTitle: 'CRS Frontend Unit-tests - test results'
        },
        jsonReporter: {
            stdout: false,
            outputFile: 'testresults/results.json' // defaults to none
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage',
            includeAllSources: true,
            reporters: [
                { type: 'html', subdir: 'html' },
                { type: 'json', subdir: 'json' }
            ]
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,
        failOnEmptyTestSuite: false
    });
};
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Do yo happen to have found the solution for this please?

Answer (score 4):

Please do the following changes if you using angular CLI 1.7.X

~/src/test.ts

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\/app\/.*\.ts$/);
```

~/src/tsconfig.spec.json

```
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: This works.  Should be the accepted answer.   Also not that the order of imports in this file matters.  Do not format or reorder the file when making modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using the [`karma-sabarivka-reporter`](https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter) to pick up missed source files into coverage.